# How do I merge 2 zoo/data.frame objects on closest date?

Tags: r, dataframe, zoo

Suppose I have the following 2 data.frames/zoo objects (whichever you find easier to work with):

```
fmt <- "%m/%d/%Y"
lookup.df <- data.frame(date=c('1/11/1999', '2/5/1999', 
  '3/8/1999','4/5/1999','6/11/1999'), value=c(1,2,3,4,5))
lookup.df$date <- as.Date(lookup.df$date, format = fmt)

main.df <- data.frame(date=c('1/10/1999', '2/1/1999', 
  '3/10/1999','4/2/1999','6/1/1999'), value=c(10,20,30,40,50))
main.df$date <- as.Date(main.df$date, format = fmt)
```

I would like to pick the closest date from the lookup table (without going over i.e. use `max(lookup.date) < main.date`) and I would like to end up with a data.frame/zoo object that looks like (column names can be whatever):

```
main.date | lookup.date | main.value | lookup.value
'1/10/1999'       NA          10          NA
'2/1/1999'     1/1/1999       20          1
'3/10/1999'    3/8/1999       30          3
'4/2/1999'     3/8/1999       40          3
'6/1/1999'     4/5/1999       50          4
```

> NOTE: I would prefer a base-R implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `findInterval` from base R to lookup each `main.df` date in `lookup.df`.

`findInterval` returns 0 if there is no matching interval so in the second line that is changed to `NA` so that the subsequent line returns an NA for such values rather than dropping them.

Note that `lookup.df` is sorted in date order in the question and we assume that that is always the case.  If not, sort `lookup.df` first.

```
ix <- findInterval(main.df$date, lookup.df$date)
ix[ix == 0] <- NA
cbind(main = main.df, lookup = lookup.df[ix, ])
```

giving:

```
     main.date main.value lookup.date lookup.value
1   1999-01-10         10          NA           NA
1.1 1999-02-01         20  1999-01-01            1
3   1999-03-10         30  1999-03-08            3
3.1 1999-04-02         40  1999-03-08            3
4   1999-06-01         50  1999-04-05            4
```

Comment: First time I see `findInterval()`... Great short cut! An upvote from me.

Comment: added handling for no-match to this answer as this sometimes happened in the real data set.

Answer (score 1):

A `base R` approach is,

```
# Converting date column into date format.
lookup.df[,"date"] <- as.Date(lookup.df[,"date"],"%m/%d/%Y")
main.df[,"date"] <- as.Date(main.df[,"date"],"%m/%d/%Y")

# Finding the index number under the defined condition.
index <- sapply(1:nrow(main.df), function(i){

        diff <- as.numeric(main.df[i,"date"] - lookup.df[,"date"])
        diff[diff<=0] <-NA
        which.min(diff)

        })

out <- data.frame(main.df,lookup.df[index,]) 

out[,c(1,3,2,4)]
```

gives,

```
          date     date.1 value value.1
1   1999-01-10 1999-01-01    10       1
1.1 1999-02-01 1999-01-01    20       1
3   1999-03-10 1999-03-08    30       3
3.1 1999-04-02 1999-03-08    40       3
4   1999-06-01 1999-04-05    50       4
```